# Compare dataframes on set datatype

Tags: python, pandas

The first dataframe has a column called "name" that I need to compare with a column in another dataframe. The problem is that even if 2 words match instead of 3, it is OK. For e.g. "amar ajay patil" is same as "amar patil" because the person is the same even if middle name is missing. How do I achieve this?

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

myst="""shantanu prabhakar oak, 905034 , 19:44   
amar ajay patil, 905094  , 19:33
manoj ashok singh,  905154 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols=['name', 'customer_id', 'current_tm']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

My second dataframe looks like this...

```
myst="""shantanu PRABHAKAR oak, 905034 , 19:44   
amar   patil, 905094  , 19:33
manoje ashoka singh,  905154 ,   21:56

"""
u_cols=['ledger_name', 'customer_id', 'current_tm']

myf = StringIO(myst)
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(myst), sep=',', names = u_cols)
```

This works as expected:

```
df.merge(df1, left_on=df.name.str.lower(), right_on=df1.ledger_name.str.lower())
```

But this does not and I get an error:

```
df.merge(df1, left_on=df.name.str.lower().apply(set), right_on=df1.ledger_name.str.lower().apply(set))
```

---

Update:

I tried to convert the column type to "set" because the sequence of names may change. "patil amar ajay" is still the same person and should match with "amar ajay patil".

Comment: so `amar ajay patil` should merge with `amar   patil` ? Ot typo in data?

Comment: @jezrael yes, both are same.